# Django template extending

Tags: django, django-templates

I am new with Django and trying to understand how to use templates and I have an issue with template extending. I have 3 templates. the first one in the **base.html**

```
{% load staticfiles%}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{%static 'css/main.css'%}">

    <title>Home</title>
</head>
<body >
<div class="page-header">
    <h1><a href="/">Django Project</a></h1>
</div>

<div class="content container">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            {%block content %}

            {%endblock%}
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-4">

            {%block lastposts %}

            {%endblock%}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Second one is **post_list.html** (which I render from views)

```
{% extends 'blog/base.html' %}

{% block content %}

{%for post in posts %}
    <a href=""><h1>{{post.title}}</h1></a>
    <p>{{post.text|linebreaks}}</p>
    <p><b>Author: </b>{{post.author}}</p>
    <p><b>Published Date: </b>{{post.published_date}}</p>
{%endfor%}

{% endblock %}
```

and **latest_posts.html**

```
{% extends 'blog/base.html' %}
{% block lastposts %}
<h3>Latest Posts</h3>

{%for post in posts%}
<a href=""><h4>{{post.title}}</h4></a>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

The problem is that the content of latest_posts.html does not show up. I know that something is wrong. In that case how I can use extending in django to to separate my code in these 3 files. Thanks.

*UPDATE

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.utils import timezone

from .models import Post


# Create your views here.
def post_list(request):
    posts = Post.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('published_date')
    return render(request, 'blog/post_list.html', {'posts': posts})
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.post_list, name='post_list'),
]
```

Comment: Are you able to see the base.html template in browser? And are you sure you have data in `posts` (If not, you should be able to see the `Latest Posts` heading at least)?

Comment: Everything appears except latest_posts.html content and also I can't see Lates Posts heading

Comment: Do you even render the latest_post.html in a view? Show us your views and project tree (folders and files).

Comment: What template are you rendering in a view? Since post_list and latest_posts both extend base.html, it's not clear to me what you are rendering and how you are expecting this to work.

Comment: I render only post_list. As I said I know that something is wrong but I don't know what exactly. I just want to keep all these 3 parts of code separate. Also if I am  doing wrong I can I extend same base in different templates. @Dainel

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display the contents of latest_posts.html in post_list.html, you'll have to include it

**post_list.html**

```
{% extends 'blog/base.html' %}

{% block content %}

{%for post in posts %}
<a href=""><h1>{{post.title}}</h1></a>
<p>{{post.text|linebreaks}}</p>
<p><b>Author: </b>{{post.author}}</p>
<p><b>Published Date: </b>{{post.published_date}}</p>
{%endfor%}

{% endblock %}


{%block lastposts %}
{% include 'blog/latest_posts.html' %}
{% endblock %}
```

**latest_posts.html** (only remove the `extend` and `block` tags)

```
<h3>Latest Posts</h3>

{%for post in posts%}
<a href=""><h4>{{post.title}}</h4></a>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: But how to display latest_posts in base.html like I am doing with post_list?

Comment: Share your views.py and urls.py

Comment: Extending a template takes the structure of your base template and applies it to the one you are calling the `extend` in. The latter file just provides content to fill the `block`s of your base template. To display the contents of a third file you must `include` it. You don't do that in your `base.html`, but simply define the `block`s. 
Are you sure your `urls.py` points to your `base.html` and not `post_list.html`?

Comment: I updated my question where you can find vies.py and urls.py. I tried to include like you said but it does not work

Comment: Sorry, meant to aks if you are sure that your `views.py` render to `base.html` and not `post_list.html`. Your update show's that you render to `post_list.html` as I suspected.

Comment: Yes I render post_list.html. Everything works great if i do not add latest_post.html

Comment: I just edited my example to remove `block` tags from `latest_posts.html`